# Cannot find gtk/gtk.h when building nativefiledialog on Fedora 37

Tags: cmake, gtk, gtk3, fedora

I am using [nativefiledialog-cmake](https://github.com/aarcangeli/nativefiledialog-cmake) in my C++ project as a submodule. When I generate the build files using CMake, it does not generate properly as it cannot find the `gtk/gtk.h` file needed for one of nativefiledialog's source files : `nfd_gtk.c`.

---

I have installed the following GTK and GTK dependency packages:

```
gtk2
gtk3
gtk4
gtk2-devel
gtk3-devel
gtk4-devel
gtk4-devel-tools

glib
glib-devel
gdk-pixbuf2-devel
atk
atk-devel
gobject-introspection
gobject-introspection-devel
libepoxy
libepoxy-devel
```

and `ls /usr/include | grep gtk` returns

```
gtk-2.0
gtk-3.0
gtk-4.0
gtk-unix-print-2.0
```

The GTK headers are inside these folders.

---

This is nativefiledialog-cmake's CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
set(SOURCES src/nfd_common.c)

macro(REQUIRE_INCLUDE_FILE path name)
    CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(${path} ${name})
    if (NOT ${name})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "${path} not found")
    endif ()
endmacro()
    
# add specific implementations
if (WIN32)
    REQUIRE_INCLUDE_FILE(windows.h HAS_WINDOWS)
    list(APPEND SOURCES src/nfd_win.cpp)
elseif (APPLE)
    REQUIRE_INCLUDE_FILE(AppKit/AppKit.h HAS_APPKIT)
    list(APPEND SOURCES src/nfd_cocoa.m)
elseif (UNIX)
    REQUIRE_INCLUDE_FILE(gtk/gtk.h HAS_GTK)
    list(APPEND SOURCES src/nfd_gtk.c)
elseif (UNIX)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot detect your system, please report to https://github.com/aarcangeli/nativefiledialog-cmake/issues")
endif ()

add_library(nativefiledialog ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(nativefiledialog PUBLIC src/include)
```

I have tried adding this line (returned from `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`) to tell the compiler where the GTK headers are located with no avail:

```
set(FLAGS "${FLAGS} -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sysprof-4 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cloudproviders -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -pthread")
```

How do I get CMake to generate properly?

Comment: Can you please read the tag wiki for the [tag:linux] tag? I'm guessing it's not appropriate for use here. Please do the same for all of the tags that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am quite not sure how you arrived at the `set(FLAGS "${FLAGS} ...")` line, because unless you've specified some additional logic, that just creates a variable `FLAGS`, it is not a standard `CMake` variable IIRC.

Perhaps what you meant to use was [target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#command:target_compile_options), where you can specify additional compile options to a given target which in your case is most likely `nativefiledialog`. That might fix your issue i.e.:

```
target_compile_options(nativefiledialog PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${DEBUG_FLAGS}>")
target_compile_options(nativefiledialog PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${RELEASE_FLAGS}>")
```

Or in your case:

```
target_compile_options(nativefiledialog PUBLIC "${FLAGS}")
```

This however is not good practice and I would recommend rewriting `nativefiledialog`'s `CMakeLists.txt`.

Bare in mind that this is in no way your fault, the `nativefiledialog` has a very bad `CMakeLists.txt` because the author didn't use any prebuild `CMake` functionalities like [find_package(GTK)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTK.html).

Comment: Thanks! I managed to find a newer fork of the repo I linked which uses PKG to find GTK so I can still use it as a submodule.